# На что может содержать ссылку?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

На что может содержать ссылку аргумент в `template <class Type>`?
Вроде может ссылаться на тип, на константу, на enum...  Может же? А еще на что?
Можете привести примеры?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Type` может являться **любым типом** *(массивом, указателем на функцию, ссылкой, другим шаблонным типом, ...)* языка `C++` или некоторым альясом для соответствующего типа. Возможные типы не закреплены в стандарте, и ответственность за верное использование шаблонов ложится на программиста.

*Хорошие примеры использования шаблонных типов вы можете найти, например, в библиотеке [**boost.**](http://www.boost.org/)* Также рекомендую к прочтению книги Александреску и Гуртового.

---

Выдержка из стандарта про шаблонные параметры, про возможные типы упоминаний нет:

> C++03, 14.1, Template parameters:
>
> A template defines a family of classes or functions.
>
> ```
> template-declaration:
>     exportopt template < template-parameter-list > declaration
> template-parameter-list:
>     template-parameter
>      template-parameter-list , template-parameter
>
> template-parameter:
>     type-parameter
>     parameter-declaration
> type-parameter:
>     class identifieropt
>     class identifieropt = type-id
>     typename identifieropt
>     typename identifieropt = type-id
>     template < template-parameter-list > class
> ```
>
> identifieropt
>         template < template-parameter-list > class
> identifieropt = id-expression
>
> A type-parameter defines its
> identifier to be a type-name (if
> declared with class or typename) or
> template-name (if declared with
> template) in the scope of the template
> declaration.

Answer (score 2):

На все.

1. `template<int&>`
2. `template<bool&>`
3. `template Arra<void *&>`